# create a 3D map

Tags: navigation, mapping, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I would like to create a dedicated device to create and save a 3D map.
I have seen that to stock this map, an octomap would be needed.

The best method I have seen on ROS is loam_continous but it has been remove for commercial purposes.

What tools do you recommand ? I got an IMU and laser(s).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215974/create-a-3d-map/) by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2015-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess there are still some forks out there,
it was under BSD license so I guess you can still use the code.
(Might anyone correct me if I am wrong with that license thing... )

I am also not sure if there is anything you need more than the code itself, somehow the description says that you need
some additional files:
https://github.com/dimatura/loam_continuous

For RGBD Cameras there is rtabmap:
http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap, I do not know if this is any use for you,
but maybe somehow together with this: http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2015-09-02**:
Thanks I will check on that

**Comment by [ARCHANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25663/archana/) on 2016-02-01**:
Hi TomSon can you please tell me how to build 3d map with hokuyo utm 30-lx using loam_continuous. I downloaded the code and when i use it with data sets provided then in rviz i can view pointclouds spinning. But instead of running bagfile when i connect my sensor then nothing comes up. thanks

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2016-02-02**:
You are at the same step I were. Dont forget you need a servo to do back and forward mouvement with your hokuyo. I got also a pointcloud spinning without a correct phasing.

**Comment by [ARCHANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25663/archana/) on 2016-02-02**:
can you suggest me which servo i have to use?

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2016-02-02**:
If I had to do it again, one of dynamixel pro would be interested for the total weight to rotate.

**Comment by [ARCHANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25663/archana/) on 2016-02-02**:
Can you please tell me specifically which dynamixel i have to purchase? And please guide me step by step how to interface ros, laser and dynamixel with each other.

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2016-02-02**:
I dont know specifically, it depends of the wieght of your system. I can't guide you trough the steps because I didn't test it myself first. I just test with the bag like you.

**Comment by [ARCHANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25663/archana/) on 2016-02-02**:
That's ok but i want to ask you one thing. In the programs of loam package why the subscriber and advertisers are name as camera, cam_to_init, and so on. Are they predefined for aparticular sensor?

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2016-02-03**:
I dont think so.